# How do I can setup Laravel with Tailwindcss base?

Tags: laravel

I try to plugin Tailwindcss in laravel 8 through Laravel mix but it doesn't run. How can I plugin Tailwindcss?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: see if this helps. https://tailwindcomponents.com/blog/how-to-install-tailwindcss-in-laravel-8